# Reconhecer quando meu Android dá response a um ping de bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Preciso saber o que é necessário para que meu programa Android detecte quando meu *bluetooth* está respondendo a um comando ping em *bluetooth*.

Tipo estão disparando ping com **l2ping** contra o meu celular, em meu celular quero detectar isso.